# Confused with a proof involving minimal polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, minimal-polynomials

I am currently reading a proof of Galois's Great Theorem and there is a certain part that I do not understand. I will not present the whole proof given in my text. I will instead try to present the necessary parts to understand my question. Here's how it goes:

Let $K$ be a splitting field of $f(X)$ over $F$ and assume that $G \equiv \text{Gal}(K/F)$ is a soluble group. Assume that $G$ is non-trivial and let
$$\{e\} = G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \cdots \triangleleft G_k = G$$
be a chain of subgroups such that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian. In fact, every quotient
is cyclic of prime order. Let the order of $G_{k-1}/G$ be $p$ for some prime $p$.
Let
$$L = G_{k-1}^* \equiv \text{Fix}_K(G_{k-1}).$$
The proof uses induction to conclude that there is a radical extension $E$ of $L$ containing $K$. By adjoining an element $\varepsilon \neq 1$ such that $\varepsilon^p = 1$ to $E$, if necessary, we may also assume that $X^p -1$ splits in $E$. The proof goes on and states other things that are unnecessary for this question. Here's the part that I do not understand: Now, since $\varepsilon^p = 1$ and $\varepsilon \neq 1$, the minimum polynomial of $\varepsilon$ over $F$ divides
$$X^{p-1} + X^{p-2} + \cdots + X +1.$$
How do we know that the minimum polynomial of $\varepsilon$ divides the above polynomial? I know that this must be true if and only if $\varepsilon$ is a root to the above polynomial, but I can't seem to understand how the above polynomial evaluates to zero when we replace the indeterminant with $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Note that the polynomial in question is simply $(X^p-1)/(X-1)$, and $\epsilon$ is a root of the numerator but not of the denominator.

Comment: Ohhhh I see! Just simple polynomial division, right? So this result shows that the sum of the roots of unity is always zero. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed, or use formula for finite geometric sum. The fact that the $p$-th roots of unity sum up to 0 is witnessed by the fact that $X^p-1$ has no term of degree $p-1$.